# TypeError: Cannot call method "split" of undefined in SuiteScript

Tags: javascript, netsuite, suitescript, suitescript2.0

I am new to scripting and I am trying to create a script in Netsuite that would look at the lines in a sales order and verify if there's a discount item. If there's a discount item, then the script looks at the item just before it, takes the value for field class and updates the discount item's class. 
I am getting Cannot call method "split" of undefined as an error and I am unsure why.

```
/**
 * @NApiVersion 2.x
 * @NScriptType UserEventScript
 * @NModuleScope SameAccount
 */
define(["N/record"], function (r){
    function afterSubmitUpdateDiscountClass(context) {

        var currentRecord = context.currentRecord;
        var numLines = currentRecord.getLineCount({
            sublistId: 'item'});

        for(var i=0; i < numLines; i++) {
            var currentItemType = currentRecord.getCurrentSublistValue ({
                sublistID: 'item',
                fieldID: 'itemType',
                line: i});

            if (currentItemType == 'discountitem') {
                var newClass = currentRecord.getCurrentSublistValue ({
                    sublistID : 'item',
                    fieldID: 'class',
                    line: i-1});
                currentRecord.selectLine({
                    sublistID: 'item',
                    line: i })
                currentRecord.setCurrentSublistValue ({
                    sublistID : 'item',
                    fieldID: 'class',
                    value : newClass });

                currentRecord.commitLine({
                    sublistID: 'item' });

            }
        }
    }
    return {
        afterSubmit: afterSubmitUpdateDiscountClass
    }
})
```

Comment: You need to show the code where you actually call `split()` in order for us to see the problem. You must be passing something into it with the wrong type.

Comment: @EdwardBull, I never call the split function. That's why I don't understand why I'm getting this error.

Comment: @AbedTimsah did you end up filing a case, if you did, could you share that with me?

Answer (score 1):

Try deleting the script record and recreating it. There have been reports in Slack about that error recently and recreating the script record has helped a few.

Answer (score 1):

Encountered this the other day, I just filed a support case with NetSuite since I was not able to find a workaround.

Comment: Thank you I might do that as well

Comment: Rusty, what is the case number?

Answer (score 0):

You are using currentRecord.getCurrentSublistValue incorrectly. getCurrentSublistValue has no line property and is used on dynamic records after record.selectLine

In a user event context you should be calling currentRecord.getSublistValue

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I did end up making that change yesterday after I noticed it. Unfortunately, I'm still getting the same error.

Comment: If you are still getting the error please update your code until it’s the most correct form that still has shows the error

Comment: i.e. please update the code you posted here with what you are currently using that throws the error. If we can narrow this down that helps others with the same issue.